# How to Pipe `tcpdump` and the `until statement` into a Single and Working Shell Script?

Tags: pipe, tcpdump, broken-pipe

I have composed the following script:

`sudo tcpdump -vv -n -s 0 -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx | until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]] do sleep 1 done killall -9 'Pages'`,

where `xx.xxx.xx.xx` is a particular IP address, and where `sudo tcpdump -vv -n -s 0 -k NP`, obviously, continuously checks for active connections, and `| grep xx.xxx.xx.xx` filters out the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address out of all the active connections tcpdump finds.
This filtered out IP address is then piped on to the `until statement`, where:

`| until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]] do sleep 1 done`

is supposed to check when there is no connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address. If such a connection exists, the `until statement` is supposed to sleep for one second only, and continue checking. If, on the contrary, such a connection does not exists, the `until statement` is supposed to pass on to the `killall` command, which, for the sake of testing, in this case is supposed to kill the running process of the OSX Pages app.

The problem is that as long as `tcpdump` and the `until statement` work perfectly fine when run separately, they do not work when piped and run together as a single script. When run together, after several seconds of what looks like the script seemingly running (but not printing the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address, which is not as it is supposed to work), `tcpdump` returns:

`Unable to write: Broken pipe`.

Here is what I have tried so far to fix this issue:

1. Running `tcpdump` both with and without `| grep`.
2. Preceding the `until statement` with `cat`, both with `;` and without it, like this `| cat; until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]]`, and like this `| cat until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]]`.
3. Passing `tcpdump` itself or with `| grep xx.xxx.xx.xx` as a variable by putting `xargs` before `until`, like this `| xarg until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]]`.
4. While still conjoining `tcpdump` and the `until statement` with `|`, I would precede `sudo tcpdump` with `cat <<EOF | tr '\12' ' '` and add `EOF` right under `done`, in a new line, in order to be sure that when the entire command is executed, the whole `until statement` is in a single line.
5. Conjoining `tcpdump` and the `until statement` not with `|`, but either single ampersand, like this `&`, or double ampersand, like this `&&`.
6. Adding `| tail -n +1` before `until`, like this:

`| tail -n +1 | until`.

7. Putting the entire shell script inside `{` and `}`, like this:

`{ sudo tcpdump -vv -n -s 0 -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx until [[ '! xx.xxx.xx.xx' ]] do sleep 1 done killall -9 'Pages' }`.

In the case of Ad. 1, over time I am returned with the said `Unable to write: Broken pipe' error.

In the case of Ad. 2, when I use `cat;` there is no `Unable to write: Broken pipe` error, and the information about the connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address is returned slower than when without `cat;`. Again, though, Pages is closed only when I terminate the execution of the command, and not when I terminate the connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address. When I use `cat` without `;` instead, I am returned with `zsh: parse error near do'`.

In the case of Ad. 3, the whole command also returns `zsh: parse error near do'`.

In the case of Ad. 4, Terminal treats all the three pipes and the `until` part of the `until statement` as a directory, switching from the home directory to `pipe pipe pipe until>`.

In the case of Ad. 5, although slower than it should be, the script seems to be running, the connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address is printed out line by line, and no `Unable to write: Broken pipe` error is returned, but when I terminate the connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address, the `until statement` does not react to it, and Pages dossn‘t get killed. Again, Pages is closed only when I terminate the execution of the command.

In the case of Ad. 6, the Terminal gets stuck at:

`tcpdump: data link type PKTAP tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), snapshot length 524288 bytes`

of `tcpdump` for a long time, and Pages gets closed even with the entire script seemingly running, without even terminating it. Only after even more time of waiting does the Terminal return the `Unable to write: Broken pipe` error.

In the case of Ad. 7, although `tcpdump` returns the information about the connection at the normal speed, just like in the case of Ad. 1, nothing other than that happens. Pages does not get closed whatsoever, not even when I terminate the execution of the command like in the previous examples. Putting the closing `}` higher, that is, right after `done`, like this `done }`, changes nothing, and the result is exactly the same.

Since the Terminal interpreter I am using is the currently default zsh interpreter, I thought I would debug the entire command by using the zsh debugger, acronymed to `zshdb`. When I save the entire command as in Ad. 1 to a shell script file named tcpdumpuntil.sh, make it an executable file with the use of the `chmod a+x` and debug it by entering `zshdb ./tcpdumpuntil.sh` in the Terminal and executing it, the only piece of information about the correctness or not of the entire command that `zshdb` returns is `zsh<0>`. It doesn‘t return anything else and, as far as I understand, the `<0>` value means that the execution of the command is `true`, meaning that there are no errors in the overall syntax and that the entire command is executed properly. The Terminal could stay at that `zsh<0>` value for hours, and nothing else would happen. Returning the said value, `zshdb` also prints out the entire command being debugged. That printed out command being debugged is printed out in a single line, which, as I understand, is also the way it should be.

If it is true, although it is only may assumption, that the entire command is properly composed and executed, what else could I do or what else should be done for `tcpdump` and the `until statement` to work together at the same time and to make the `until statement` react to and execute when the connection with the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP address is terminated? Is it still, in spite of everything, possible that somehow the stdout of `tcpdump` is not passed on to the stdin of the `until statement`, and that the `until statement` doesn‘t read it? If so, how to make the two commands indeed share the stdout of `tcpdump`?

I want to make it clear that I checked all the threads suggested when writing this thread, and as in some of them discussed were the solutions I had already described, which do not work in my case, the other threads did not touch upon my issue, and did not include viable solutions.

P.S. I can only add that I have also tried to pipe the above `until statement` with `lsof -i :xx.xxx.xx.xx` the same way, also to no avail

I have tried all the things as described in the main message body. My expectation is that when `tcpdump` finds no connection with the particular IP address, the `until statement` should kill the particular process indicated by causing the execution of the `killall -9` command.